# a quartic polynomial in one variable

Tags: polynomials, quartics

Let

$$g(x)=ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e$$

be a polynomial of degree $4$ with $a>0$. Can we determine coefficients $a,b,c,d,e$ such that $g(x) \ge 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$? 
I'd like to make sure that my idea works.
In addition to the conditions $\Delta>0$, $P>0$, and $D>0$ given in
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function
, do we need any other condition?

Any reference, suggestion, idea, or comment is welcome. Thank you!

Comment: So you're just asking if it's possible in general? Have you tried, I dunno, $a=b=c=d=e=1$ ?

Comment: Transforming $g(x) \geq 0$ into $g(x)>0$ make your question equivalent to say that $p$ has no real roots and $a>0$. See for that [Sturm theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem) or Descartes rule of signs.

Comment: $g(x)=x^4+1$ works.

Comment: @MattiP. Pretty sure he means a more general (possibly equivalent) condition. ;-)

Comment: Yes, I mean a more general condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the loss of generality we can take $a=1$.
The we have $$f(x)=x^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e~~~~(1)$$
Let $$c \ge \frac{b^2+d^2}{4}~~~~(2)$$ Then we can re-write $f(x)$ as 
$$f(x)=\left(x^2+\frac{bx}{2}\right)^2+\left(c-\frac{b^2}{4}-\frac{d^2}{4}\right) x^2+\left(\frac{dx}{2}+1\right)^2+e-1.$$
So when $a=1$, $e\ge 1$ and (2) is met $f(x) \ge 0, \forall~ x\in R$

Comment: $e\ge 1$ and condition (2) make sure that $f(x)\ge0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. However, there might be $b,c,d,c$ which don't satisfy $e\ge 1$ and condition (2) but satisfy $f(x)\ge0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The conditions $ a=1, e \ge 1 and $c \ge {db^2+d^2)/4$ are together sufficient for $f(x) \ge 0$, this set of conditions may not be necessary.for $f(x)\ge 0$.